# Powershell Inheritance with List<CustomClass>

Tags: powershell, inheritance

So I'm stumped trying to figure out how to inherit the System.Collections.Generic.List class using a custom class in PowerShell. If I use the code example below, the script fails with the error "An error occurred while creating the pipeline." If I change the type of list from MyClass to a standard type such as String, then the code works fine. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but my searches yielded no answers...

```
Class MyClass
{
    [String]$foo
    [int]$bar
}
Class MyClassList : System.Collections.Generic.List[MyClass]
{
}
```

Comment: Classes are parsed before everything else in powershell.  The type needs to exist in the session before you attempt to use it.  This is an intended behavior.

Comment: Here are a few github issues on the project (though note this will never be "fixed" in Windows PowerShell): [one](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3641), [two](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2449), [three](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652)

Comment: Ok that helped. I was able to put MyClass into a seperate .psm1 file and use Import-Module MyClass.psm1 to get the behavior to work. That led me down a dark road and I ended up realizing I was overthinking things...back to keeping it simpler while I'm in powershell. Thanks!

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I do not see how is that intended behavior. Class should be available in the parse unit where it declared.

Comment: @PetSerAl Well, it's not and it never will be (in Windows PowerShell).